# Having issue while access the Cross origin web request from IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-10

Having issue while access the CORS (Cross origin) web request from IE 10.

When I set the Access Data Sources Across Domain in IE

```
 settings-> 
   Custom Level-> 
     security->
```

Miscellaneous to Prompt (or) disable and try to access the server web method.

The preflight request is working fine and when the actual request happens (i.e. Get) I am not getting the User credentials popup window to pass the credentials.

Whereas when I enable the Access data source across domain, the preflight is not happening here and when the actual get is invoked I am getting the popup for user credentials and it is working fine.

But, this is not the way I wanted. I need this to be a default setting at IE 10 (i.e. Prompt).

I face the issue only with IE in Firefox and chrome its working fine I am getting the user credentials popup and it is working fine.